# Cannot find testID of inner <Text> tag/component from react-native in appium with iOS device

Tags: react-native, xpath, appium, appium-ios

I'm writing tests for React Native using Appium + Java for iOS. But i has an issue that appium inspector could not find testID of react-native.
Here is my react-native demo code:

```
const App: () => Node = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      testID="SafeAreaView"
      accessible={false}
    >
      <ScrollView
        testID="scroll_view"
        accessible={false}
      >
        <Text style={styles.baseText} testID="can_see_testID_as_key">
          This is a
          <Text style={styles.innerText} testID={"cannot_see_this_testID"}> iOS test</Text>
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  innerText: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});
```

I expect to see both **can_see_testID_as_key** and **cannot_see_this_testID** in appium inspector but only see first one.

[image: Only see 1 testID="can_see_testID_as_key" ("testID" is displayed as "name" appium]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior you're seeing is due to React Native collapsing nested `<Text>` elements into a single View which renders all the text. Since there's only one view, only the top-level testID can be used.
React Native can render text with different styles using a single view because it internally draws the text using the OS APIs that support different styles for a single text object.